# How do I make a join on two tables in SQL when there are two foreign keys referencing the same primary key? It's driving me insane

Tags: mysql, sql

What the title says. I've tried connecting two tables with two foreign keys referencing the same primary key and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use table *aliases*. For example:

```
select *
from money_transfer t
join account s on t.sender_id = s.id
join account r on t.receiver_id = r.id
```

Here you can see two references to the same PK (`account.id`). The first time the table is given the alias `s` and the second time the same table is given the alias `r`. This way you can differentiate which one you want to use on each join predicate.